# Google captcha's size is weird

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I put google's recaptcha in my site and it looks really weird when I open it, here's a picture:
my form works and all i just need the recaptcha to prevent bots from spamming or idk what. Thanks!
EDIT: better picture:

[image]

Here's my html and php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    var_dump($_POST)
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha= $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $secret = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    $respo = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {
    } else {            
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="faggot.css">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="background: url('../t2.png');height: 1700px;"> <!-- body -->
    <h1 id="h1">Register</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post" name="form1" style="background: url('../t1.png');">
        <div>
        <ul class="ull" id="nameull">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="div">
                    <li class="margtop"><h2 class="tooltip" >First name<span class="red">*</span></h2></li>
                    <li class="margtop"><input id="fnamee" class="bax" type="text" name="fname" required="yes" pattern="^[a-z1-9]+"></li>
                </div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ull" style="display: inline-block;" id="lname">
            <div>
            <li class="margtop"><h2 class="tooltip" id="lnaam">Last name<span class="red">* </span></h2></li>
                    <li class="margtop"><input class="bax" type="text" name="lname" required="yes"></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ull" id="pwull">
                <li class="margtop"><h2 class="tooltip" style="margin-right: 30px;">Password<span class="red">*</span></h2><input id="pwinput" class="bax" type="password" name="pw" required="yes"><span class="tp" id="pwinc">Password       is     encrypted!</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ull" id="usrull">
        <div class="div" id="div1">
        <li>
            <h2 class="tooltip">Username<span class="red">*</span></h2>
            <input style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 100px;width: 200px;" class="bax" type="text" name="uname" required="yes"><span class="tp" id="op">Only use lowercase letters!</span>
        </li>
        </div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ull" id="emailull">
                <div class="div">
                <li class="margtop"> <h2 class="tooltip" id="emel">Email<span class="red">*</span></h2><input style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 100px;width: 300px;" class="bax" type="email" name="email" required="yes"><span class="tp" id="oep">Only one email per account!</span></li>
                </div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ull" style="margin-left: 500px;margin-top: 100px;display: inline-block;width: 130%;">
            <li><div style="" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
        <div class="div">
        <li>
           <input class="bax" id="sabmitbat" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit1">
        </li>
        </div>
        </ul>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="buttonbg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that's your true secret key I'd remove it from your example.

Comment: it's my local host, but ill remove it anyway.

Comment: nobody knows how to solve this?